# How can I set different radius for each corner of a layout programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a kotlin class that extends LinearLayouts. I use it to add a radius to my layouts. Here is the class.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.LinearLayout

class RadiusLinearLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

private lateinit var rectF: RectF
private val path = Path()
private var cornerRadius = 25f

init {
    val radiusAttribute = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RadiusLinearLayout)
    cornerRadius = radiusAttribute.getFloat(R.styleable.RadiusLinearLayout_cornerRadius, 25f)
    radiusAttribute.recycle()
}

override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    rectF = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
    resetPath()
}

override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val save = canvas.save()
    canvas.clipPath(path)
    super.draw(canvas)
    canvas.restoreToCount(save)
}

override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val save = canvas.save()
    canvas.clipPath(path)
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
    canvas.restoreToCount(save)
}

private fun resetPath() {
    path.reset()
    path.addRoundRect(rectF, this.cornerRadius, this.cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
    path.close()
}
}
```

I also have a styleable.xml file to set the radius of the layout when defined on an xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RadiusLinearLayout">
        <attr name="cornerRadius" format="float"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Here's an example.

```
    <test.com.RadiusLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerLinearLayoutCF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cornerRadius="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

I would like to set the radius for each individual corner of the layout programmatically. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to set the radius for each individual corner of the
>   layout programmatically. Is there a way to do so?

Yes, you need to declare function and corresponding fields to store your radiuses, something like this:

```
private var topLeft = 0f
private var topRight = 0f
private var bottomLeft = 0f
private var bottomRight = 0f

public fun setRadius(topLeft: Float = 0f, topRight: Float = 0f, bottomLeft: Float = 0f, bottomRight: Float = 0f) {
    this.topLeft = topLeft
    ...
    invalidate()
}

private fun resetPath() {
    path.reset()
    val corners = floatArrayOf(
                topLeft, topLeft,
                topRight, topRight,
                bottomLeft, bottomLeft, 
                bottomRight, bottomRight
        )
    path.addRoundRect(rectF, corners, Path.Direction.CW)
    path.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bracadabra's implementation works and I marked it as the right answer, I just wanted to share what it looks like once implemented

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import profitlifter.com.R.styleable.*

class RadiusDisjointFrameLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : 
FrameLayout(context, attrs) {

private lateinit var rectF: RectF
private val path = Path()
private var cornerTopLeft = 25f
private var cornerTopRight = 25f
private var cornerBottomLeft = 25f
private var cornerBottomRight = 25f

init {
    val radiusAttribute = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, RadiusDisjointLayout)
    cornerTopLeft = radiusAttribute.getFloat(RadiusDisjointLayout_radius_top_left, 25f)
    cornerTopRight = radiusAttribute.getFloat(RadiusDisjointLayout_radius_top_right, 25f)
    cornerBottomLeft = radiusAttribute.getFloat(RadiusDisjointLayout_radius_bottom_left, 25f)
    cornerBottomRight = radiusAttribute.getFloat(RadiusDisjointLayout_radius_bottom_right, 25f)
    radiusAttribute.recycle()
}

override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    rectF = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
    resetPath()
}

override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val save = canvas.save()
    canvas.clipPath(path)
    super.draw(canvas)
    canvas.restoreToCount(save)
}

override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val save = canvas.save()
    canvas.clipPath(path)
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
    canvas.restoreToCount(save)
}

private fun resetPath() {
    path.reset()
    val cornersRadius = floatArrayOf(cornerTopLeft, cornerTopLeft, cornerTopRight, cornerTopRight, cornerBottomLeft, cornerBottomLeft, cornerBottomRight, cornerBottomRight
    )
    path.addRoundRect(rectF, cornersRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
    path.close()
}
}
```

Here's the styleable.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RadiusDisjointLayout">
        <attr name="radius_top_left" format="float"/>
        <attr name="radius_top_right" format="float"/>
        <attr name="radius_bottom_left" format="float"/>
        <attr name="radius_bottom_right" format="float"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test.com.Classes.RadiusDisjointFrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
app:radius_top_left="65"
app:radius_top_right="5"
app:radius_bottom_left="25"
app:radius_bottom_right="15"/>
```